# Loop inside a react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I have the following react component

```
const Layout = () => {
return (
    <ThemeProvider>
        <Flex wrap>
            <Box width={[1, 1 / 3]}>
                <Text bold>Targeting</Text>

                <Iconlist text="Something"/>

            </Box>
            <Box width={[1, 1 / 3]}>
                <Text bold>Tactics</Text>
            </Box>
            <Box width={[1, 1 / 3]}>
                <Text bold>Results</Text>
            </Box>

        </Flex>
    </ThemeProvider>

)
};
export default Layout;
```

I want to implement something like this:

```
...
<Iconlist text="Something"/>
<Iconlist text="Something else"/>
<Iconlist text="Something else else"/>
<Iconlist text="Something ...."/>
...
```

How can I write a loop that can do the above i.e. display multiple Iconlist component. I know how to use props to change the "something" value but I am unable to run a loop.

I tried this:

```
<Box width={[1, 1 / 3]}>
                <Text bold>Targeting</Text>

                {
                    for(var i=0;i<=5;i++){
                    <Iconlist text="Something"/>
                }
                }

            </Box>
```

But I am guessing that's not the correct way to inject javascript in between. I am a beginner to React and trying to learn how to do this. What's the best practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

> The `map()` method creates a new array with the results of calling a
>   provided function on every element in the calling array.

**Example**

```
<Box width={[1, 1 / 3]}>
  <Text bold>Targeting</Text>
  { Array(5).map((i) => (<Iconlist key={i} text={`Something ${i}`} />)) } 
</Box>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<Box width={[1, 1 / 3]}>
  <Text bold>Targeting</Text>
    {
      ['something',
       'something else',
       'something else else',
       'something ...',
      ].map((text, index) => <Iconlist key={index} text={text}/>)
    }
</Box>
```

Comment: It would be highly recommended to add some explanations of the code you have posted. Simply providing sample code is not the best method to learning programming, and will not benefit the post creator as much as it would if how  and why the code was explained. A well-detailed answer will establish your credibility in the community, and your answers will attract up-votes.

Answer (score 0):

You need first to declare the text values in array like this

```
const texts = ['something', 'something else' ..]
```

And in the render method add the following

```
{ texts.map((text) => <Iconlist text={text}/>) }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store your items in an array in the **state**:

```
...

constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {
    items: [
      'something',
      'something else',
      'something else else',
      'something ...'
    ]
  }
}

...
```

...and then map over the array in your **render** function:

```
...

{
  this.state.items.map(item => <Iconlist text={ item } />)
}

...
```

This will then re-render when you update the state.

You could also pass in the array as a **prop** and then render like this:

```
...

{
  this.props.items.map(item => <Iconlist text={ item } />)
}

...
```